# Android: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.app.myapp/files/myfile.pdf

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-fileprovider

I have a PDF file I download from an API and save to internal storage using `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`. When I attempt to open the file I get the error in the title, `Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.app.myapp/files/myfile.pdf`.

Code that saves files:

```
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), fileName);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileBytes);
LaunchIntent(filePath);
```

Code where error occurs:

```
 public static void LaunchIntent(string fileLocation)
    {
        // now create an activity which points to the file
        var localPath = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse(fileLocation).Path;
    
        File javaFile = new File(localPath);
        //error occurs at below code
        var filePath = global::Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity,
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.PackageName + ".fileprovider",
            javaFile);
    
        var actionView = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        actionView.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        var extension = localPath.Substring(localPath.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        var mimeType = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        actionView.SetDataAndType(filePath, mimeType);
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivity(actionView);
    }
```

My file paths file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external" path="." />
  <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
  <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
  <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: why are you building your file path two completely different ways?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, still pretty new to android. can you tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: the way you build the file path in the first snippet and the second snipped are completely different.  Why are you not using the same approach in both?

Comment: I updated the code so its gives a better picture. I don't build them the same way because of the method parameter requirements for `GetUriForFile()`

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done code like this, so I can only give general debugging advice. In first code snippet, what is value of `filePath`?  Have you used a file browser app to verify that the file is where you expect?  Is the actual location of the file the same as the path in the error message? If not, have you found documentation that verifies that path in error message *should* map to the physical location? Can you find a sample app that uses GetUriForFile, download that app and verify it works? Then see what path it uses?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you pdf is saved in internal storage, Provider path for a specific path as followings:

1. `<files-path/> --> Context.getFilesDir()`
2. `<cache-path/> --> Context.getCacheDir()`
3. `<external-path/> --> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`
4. `<external-files-path/> --> Context.getExternalFilesDir(String)`
5. `<external-cache-path/> --> Context.getExternalCacheDir()`
6. `<external-media-path/> --> Context.getExternalMediaDirs()`

You can refer to: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

So change your `resources/xml/file_paths.xml`

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
<files-path name="internal_files" path="." />

</paths>
```

And adding a provider in the AndroidManifest.xml file Application tag.

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```